# Regular expression to restrict length

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a Regex for my Jquery

[RegularExpressionAttribute(@"/^[-\w\s]+$/")] which works for alphanumeric and space. But I want it to restrict its length to 147 characters.

Please help!

Comment: P.s I really enjoy using this site to visualize my regex: http://www.regexper.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[RegularExpressionAttribute(@"/^[-\w\s]{0,147}$/")]`

Comment: Above expression is not working.. its accepting more than 147 characters :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about jquery or javascript, then you have to use regular expression as below.

```
var regex = /^[-\w\s]{0,147}$/;
alert(regex.test(anyString))
```

It alerts true if "anyString" matches the given regular expression, and otherwise false.